# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in dynamic Linq-to-Sql where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Well i am using Dynamic Linq Extension library for IQueryable type of collection. My collection is of IQueryable. And I apply where cluase on it but when it enumberate it throws the exception of null reference. Please look at the below stack trace.

```
IQueryable<T> returnData = source.Where(advanceSearchParameter.AdvanceSearchText, advanceSearchParameter.AdvanceSearchValue);
```

Where is the extension method come from Dynamic extention library.

Here Source is the object of type `IQueryable<T>` and i am getting error when returnData gets executed(enumerate).

Comment: You should show us **the relevant code** ! (not just the stack trace......)

Comment: Clearly, you have a NULL reference.   Without code, we can't tell you much more than that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting Visual Studio to break when an Exception is thrown?  Go to Debug > Exceptions... and check the bow under "Thrown" next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Hopefully it will break somewhere where you can see what is null.